# percentage value for monthly data with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I have an example data as:

```
date        Product  Sales
2020-01-01.  Dell.    4
2020-01-01.  Apple.   6
2020-01-01.  Lenovo.  5
2020-01-02.  Dell.    2
2020-01-02.  Apple.   4
2020-01-02.  Lenovo.  3
```

I would like to create another column called 'percentage monthly sale' which is the obtained by the (monthly sale of a product/ total sales of all products in that month) * 100.

The output should look like this:

```
date        Product  Sales. Percentage_monthly_sale
2020-01-01.  Dell.    4.      26.6 (4/15 *100)
2020-01-01.  Apple.   6.      40.0. (6/15*100)
2020-01-01.  Lenovo.  5.      33.3.  (5/15 *100)
2020-01-02.  Dell.    2.      22.2 (2/9 *100)
2020-01-02.  Apple.   4.      44.4 (4/9 *100)
2020-01-02.  Lenovo.  3.      33.3 (3/9 *100)
```

Comment: It seems your explanation and output differ rather significantly can you clarify your question? The expected output is percentage of daily sales. But your words say that you want the total of each product over the total for the month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby transform` with a `lambda function`:

```
df['Percentage_daily_sale'] = df.groupby(
    ['date'])['Sales'].transform(lambda x: (x/x.sum()) * 100)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
          date  Product  Sales  Percentage_daily_sale
0  2020-01-01.    Dell.      4                  26.67
1  2020-01-01.   Apple.      6                  40.00
2  2020-01-01.  Lenovo.      5                  33.33
3  2020-01-02.    Dell.      2                  22.22
4  2020-01-02.   Apple.      4                  44.44
5  2020-01-02.  Lenovo.      3                  33.33
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-transform) with [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html#pandas-grouper) to get the totals then divide and multiply the Series together:

(Shown Desired Output)

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

daily_sums = df.groupby(
    pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1D')
)['Sales'].transform('sum')

df['Percentage_daily_sale'] = df['Sales'] / daily_sums * 100
```

```
        date  Product  Sales  Percentage_daily_sale
0 2020-01-01    Dell.      4              26.666667
1 2020-01-01   Apple.      6              40.000000
2 2020-01-01  Lenovo.      5              33.333333
3 2020-01-02    Dell.      2              22.222222
4 2020-01-02   Apple.      4              44.444444
5 2020-01-02  Lenovo.      3              33.333333
```

---

To get the percentage of *monthly* sales for *each* product:

(Explained Desired Behaviour)

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

monthly_product_total = df.groupby(
    [pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1M'), 'Product']
)['Sales'].transform('sum')

monthly_total = df.groupby(
    pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1M')
)['Sales'].transform('sum')

df['Percentage_Monthly_sale'] = monthly_product_total / monthly_total * 100
```

```
        date  Product  Sales  Percentage_Monthly_sale
0 2020-01-01    Dell.      4                25.000000
1 2020-01-01   Apple.      6                41.666667
2 2020-01-01  Lenovo.      5                33.333333
3 2020-01-02    Dell.      2                25.000000
4 2020-01-02   Apple.      4                41.666667
5 2020-01-02  Lenovo.      3                33.333333
```